# Ansible iptables role execution order

Tags: ansible, iptables

I have a playbook defined that executes two roles:

1. Install SSHD

```yaml
- name: install sshd
  apt:
    name: openssh-server
    state: present
    update_cache: yes
- name: Allow new incoming SYN packets on TCP port {{ssh_port}} (SSH)
  iptables:
    chain: INPUT
    protocol: tcp
    destination_port: "{{ssh_port}}"
    ctstate: NEW
    syn: match
    jump: ACCEPT
    comment: Accept new SSH connections.
    state: present
```

2. Configure IPTables

```yaml
- name: Iptables flush filter
  iptables:
    chain: "{{ item }}"
    flush: yes
  with_items:  [ 'INPUT', 'FORWARD', 'OUTPUT' ]
- name: Allow related and established connections
  iptables:
    chain: INPUT
    match: conntrack
    ctstate: ESTABLISHED,RELATED
    jump: ACCEPT
- name: Set the policy for the INPUT chain to DROP
  iptables:
    chain: INPUT
    policy: DROP
```

I thought of having the roles defined in a self-contained way. this is why the SSHD role takes care of its own firewall settings. However, this leads to a problem now:

- Executing the SSHD role first, the iptables role will delete (flush) the SSHD rule, leaving access to ssh blocked
- Executing the iptables role first, it will immediately block SSH (and therefore ansible) access, before the SSHD role can be executed to enable it again

How do I structure the playbooks correctly?

Answer (score 1):

> How do I structure the playbooks correctly?

Perhaps you shouldn't, perhaps you should edit the tasks so that you don't end up with your 'chicken-egg' problem which you have right now. Especially if you develop your roles as self-contained roles.

> Executing the SSHD role first, the iptables role will delete (flush) the SSHD rule, leaving access to ssh blocked

Ensure it doesn't. I don't have the proper technical answer right now. But I'm sure you can configure system to let iptables not delete (flush) the SSHD rule. Perhaps do some magic in between the tasks. Just ensure the roles are self-contained.

> Executing the iptables role first, it will immediately block SSH (and therefore ansible) access, before the SSHD role can be executed to enable it again

That is undesired anyway. Write Ansible in such a way to ensure this doesn't happen.